# Laravel Mocking non-injected classes

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm writing feature tests. And I would like to ask whether it is possible to mock a method of a class which is not being injected.

Situation looks like this

```
class SomeController
{
    // doing stuff
    // ...

    $taxService = new TaxService($parameters...);
    
    $amount = $taxService->calculateGovermentsCut();

    // doing more stuff
    // ...

}
```

In the feature tests I would like to mock only the ->calculateGovermentsCut() method.

The test should look like this.

```
$this->get('/page-of-that-controller')
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertSeeText('Goverments cut is xxx');
```

I realize there might be a better way how to do it. Inject that service or some other way. But I'm dealing with a legacy code and I just need a to somehow reasonable cover it with tests.

So to sumarize it. Is it possible to mock a method of a class which is not being injected in Laravel Fature tests?

Thank you, in advance!

I would like to mock a method of a class which is not being injected in Laravel Fature tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there, what you need to do is mock the service and use dependency injection or use `app()` or `resolve()` (in this case you can't use Dependeny Injection because you need to pass stuff to the constructor):

```php
Route::get('/page-of-that-controller', [SomeController::class, 'yourMethod']);

class SomeController
{
    public function yourMethod(Request $request)
    {
        // doing stuff
        // ...

        $taxService = resolve(TaxService::class, [...$parameters]);
    
        $amount = $taxService->calculateGovermentsCut();

        // doing more stuff
        // ...
    }
}
```

Have in mind that when you do `resolve(TaxService::class, [...$parameters])`, you have to match the name of each constructor's parameter with the index of the array.

Now, the test should have:

```php
$this->mock(TaxService::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('calculateGovermentsCut')
        ->andReturn(123);
});

$this->get('/page-of-that-controller')
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertSeeText('Goverments cut is xxx');
```

It is possible that `resolve` or `app` (`resolve` is an alias of `app`) may not exactly work when you need to pass data to the constructor and you are faking it (mock). But try this out and let me know.

Comment: That unfortunatelly does not work. You where correct when you were questioning whether `app()` will work when it is also necessary to pass parameters. It doesnt work with parametrs. But still worth remembering this. Thank you!